# Cant't Get Equinox Weaving to Work in Installable Feature

Tags: eclipse-rcp, equinox, load-time-weaving

I have a bundle that does binary weaving at runtime using `org.eclipsse.equinoix.weaving.hook`. It works when I package it as a stand-alone app with the bundle that does the weaving specified in config.ini with a default start level.

However, I also created an installable feature with my plug-ins. When I install the feature into an Eclipse IDE, the weaving does not occur when I launch the IDE. Starting the IDE with  -console and looking at the bundle status, I see my weaving bundle with a status of STARTING. All of the bundles it depends on have a status ACTIVE. If I manually start my weaving bundle from the OSGI console, weaving works from then on. Even with subsequent launches it works, without having to manually start it on the OSGI console. But if I re-instal the feature, then I have to manually start the bundle one time on the OSGI console for weaving to work.

How should I configure the app so weaving works without intervening on the OSGI console? I tried setting different start levels for my weaving bundle and for the `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook` bundle, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the description here [Equinox Aspects – Quick-start guide](https://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/aspects/equinox-aspects-quick-start.php)
The most important part, I stumbled upon in the past, was the co-location of the weaving bundle. If you install your feature you must assure that the system bundle `org.eclipse.osgi` and bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook` must be in the same directory (co-located).
And you should check that bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj` is started with start level 1.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the quick-start page. I have the system bundle and `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook` in the plugins directory together. I tried setting the start level of `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj` to 1 (using the simple configurator, so I edited bundles.info), to no effect. One thing I don't understand is that in my stand-alone app there is no `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook` or `org.eclipse.equinox.wweaving.aspectj` bundles in the plugins folder, but weaving works. In the eclipse instance into which I install my feature, those plugins are there.

Comment: Which versions of Eclipse and AspectJ are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mars.2 Release 4.5.2 (recent download of current `Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers`). The `org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj` plug-in is version 1.0.300.I20130319-1000, and the `org.aspectj.runtime` and `org.aspectj.weaver` plugins are version 1.7.3.20130613144500-a.

Comment: I have something working, but I'm not sure it's the right solution. I have an  `IStartup` instance registered by an `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension, which calls my weaving bundle's activator and has it register its weaving hook. The start level setting in the app config puts the bundle into the STARTING state, but it's not going to go ACTIVE until someone access it, right? If so, then early startup is the best way I know to make weaving available when needed. But I wonder if there's a way to do it synchronously, i.e. guarantee registration completes before weaving is needed.

Comment: I have some examples here https://github.com/peterkir/example.aspectj and  I will update and try to run them with Mars.2 and corresponding AJDT version. Ping back if it is working.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using aspectj, but just registering a weaving hook with `(ServiceRegistration<WeavingHook>) context.registerService(WeavingHook.class.getName(), new MyWeavingHook(), properties)`. But I think I'm doing the equivalent of your examples. In the manifest of the plug-in that registers the weaving hook, I have `Eclipse-SupplementBundle: my.weaving.target`. But the start method of the activator doesn't get called when my.weaving.target is activated, which I expect. It's activated only if I load a class from the weaving bundle, which I do in an early startup. Is my expectation valid?